# Pass NULL value for java.sql.Types.ARRAY of java.sql.Types.STRUCT to Oracle using Java

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I am trying to invoke a stored procedure from Java. The procedure accepts two parameters which are ARRAY of STRUCT. I want to pass a null value to those.

```
create or replace FUNCTION inst_into_table_sp
(    
  v_array1  in cfg.t_array1_name_obj_tab,
  v_array2  in cfg.t_array2_obj_tab,
  v_var3    in varchar2,
  v_var4    in varchar2,
  v_err_msg out varchar2
)
...
```

The object and collection types are created as:

```
create or replace TYPE T_ARRAY2_OBJ AS OBJECT ( 
  code        VARCHAR2(60 CHAR),
  name        VARCHAR2(60 CHAR),
  description VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
);
/
create or replace TYPE T_ARRAY2_OBJ_TAB IS TABLE OF CFG.T_ARRAY2_OBJ
/

create or replace TYPE T_ARRAY1_NAME_OBJ AS OBJECT ( 
  FIELD1 VARCHAR2(1 CHAR),
  FIELD2 VARCHAR2(60 CHAR),
  FIELD3 VARCHAR2(1 CHAR),
  FIELD4 VARCHAR2(60 CHAR),
  FIELD5 VARCHAR2(1 CHAR),
  FIELD6 VARCHAR2(60 CHAR)
);
/
create or replace TYPE T_ARRAY1_NAME_OBJ_TAB IS TABLE OF CFG.T_ARRAY1_NAME_OBJ
/
```

For each array I am creating a descriptor like below -

```
arrayDescriptor1 = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("CFG.T_ARRAY1_NAME_OBJ_TAB", oconn);
structDescriptor1 = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("CFG.T_ARRAY1_OBJ", oconn);

Object[][] arrObj1 = new Object[3][3];
ARRAY arr1 = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, arrObj1);

arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("CFG.T_ARRAY2_OBJ_TAB", oconn);
structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("CFG.T_ARRAY2_OBJ",oconn);

Object[][] arrObj = new Object[5][3];
ARRAY arr = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, arrObj);
```

This is how I am creating Inputs

```
inputs.addEntry(Types.ARRAY, input_arr_1);
inputs.addEntry(Types.ARRAY, input_arr_2);
inputs.addEntry(Types.VARCHAR, var3);
inputs.addEntry(Types.VARCHAR, var4);

PreparedStatement callableStatement = SPUtilities.prepareStoredProcedure(oracleConnection,CFG_SCHEMA,SP_TO_INSERT,inputs,outputs);
callableStatement.setNull(1,Types.ARRAY,"ARRAY");
callableStatement.setNull(2,Types.ARRAY,"ARRAY");

SPUtilities.runSP ( callableStatement );
```

But I am always getting following error -

```
invalid name pattern: dbo.array
```

dbo is my username. I don't know where it is picking it up from.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the type names, not a generic value `"ARRAY":

```
callableStatement.setNull(1,Types.ARRAY,"CFG.T_ARRAY1_NAME_OBJ_TAB");
callableStatement.setNull(2,Types.ARRAY,"CFG.T_ARRAY2_OBJ_TAB");
```

But in your question you've shown `inst_into_table_sp` as a function. if it is, and your `SPUtilities` wrapper is dealing with that and registering the out parameter for you (via the `outputs` argument, which you haven't shown being set), then your parameter indexes are wrong and should be:

```
callableStatement.setNull(2,Types.ARRAY,"CFG.T_ARRAY1_NAME_OBJ_TAB");
callableStatement.setNull(3,Types.ARRAY,"CFG.T_ARRAY2_OBJ_TAB");
```

... since the first bound parameter is the return value from the function.

Comment: This change is giving same error. invalid name pattern: DBO.T_ARRAY2_OBJ_TAB

Comment: @greengrassbluesky - with the CFG schema prefix? The second one should be STRUCT not ARRAY too; updated.

Comment: Yes. i got error with CFG.T_ARRAY2_OBJ_TAB. Do i need to set null for Struct ? I am only setting it for array because its an array of Struct. STRUCT is not a parameter by itself.

Comment: Hmm really ? Even though it is not a parameter ? what should be the parameter index since it is not a parameter ?

Comment: No, not really, I was misreading the relationship between the PL/SQL and Java code. Updated to show the two type names properly (I think), to match the function spec.

Comment: Yep... exactly thats how I am passing them.

Comment: Actually sorry..my bad..i didnt compile.. when I use the setNULL with parameters you have written above. I get "Parameter Type Conflict" Not sure what that means :(

Comment: Against which line? You've only shown one collection type's `createDescriptor()` call, do you actually have one for `T_ARRAY_NAME_OBJ_TAB` too? You've implied you do.

Comment: Its not really giving me the line number. I added code for ARRAY1. Although I am passing data in it, which is good data that is inserted into DB with this same call. Please note: that with both the arrays, if there is data SP and Java code both are working fine. Problem is only when they are NULL .

Comment: @greengrassbluesky - eventually got this setup based on your code (reordered and tweaked to make it work at all) and I don't have a problem running it, with my modification above. However, your question is confusing; you've shown `inst_into_table_sp` as a function but haven't given the return type. If it is a function, and your `SPUtilities` is dealing with that, then you have the parameter indexes wrong - which would give that error.

Comment: ok... sorry about the confusion. didnt realize that i didnt give all the details. but, help me understand what does "parameterIndex" refer to ? I will add SPUtilities code as well. Thank you very much for helping me debug this.

Comment: The first argument to `setNull()` is the parameter index. Look at the SQL call that is actually being made to the function; it will be something like `call ? = inst_into_table_sp(?,?,?,?,?)`. The first parameter, indicated by the ? bind placeholder, is the function return value. The second is the v_array1 argument; the third is the v_array2 argument. Your SPUtilities seems to be hiding how those are set from you. When you modify it outside that you still need to use the right index into those placeholders.

Comment: @greengrassbluesky - I don't think you want to post the whole of SPUtilities, and I don't really want decipher and explain it. Walk through it and try to understand what it's doing in the calls you make to it, particularly how it handles the SQL you're running and what it does with the input/output parameters you pass it. You might even discover it already has a way to set nulls internally, if it's able to set not-null values.